# How to upload multiple Excel files on plotly-Dash

Tags: python, flask, plotly-dash, dashboard

I'm trying to make a plotly-Dash app where users can upload their Excel files (generated by an analytical piece of lab equipment) and have their files collated by sample name for further calculations to be performed. The end goal here is to generate an Excel file within the app which is exported back to the user. The code works really well in Jupyter Notebook, using easygui to upload the files, but translating this to Dash app, and following the documentation here: https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/upload (example 1), has thrown several issues.

Code in Jupyter notebook which works well:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import easygui
import os.path


# In[1]:


files = easygui.fileopenbox(filetypes = "*xlsx", multiple = True)
basename = []
for file in files:
    base = os.path.basename(file)
    basename.append(base)
basename


# In[3]:


heightdf = pd.DataFrame()
for filename in basename:
    df_h = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name= "Height - Raw data")
    df_h['filename'] = filename
    split = filename.split(" Run")
    df_h['sample'] = split[0]
    time_rounded =[]
    for i in df_h["t [s]"]:
        j = round(0.5*round(i/0.5), 2)
        time_rounded.append(j)
    df_h["time_rounded"] = time_rounded
    print(filename)
    heightdf = heightdf.append(df_h)
```

Here, when I print `basename`, I get the expected output -something like `[file1.xslx,file2.xslx, file3.xslx]`  etc. The information within these files then gets collated and appended to a dataframe (I realise that this is now depracated...) .

Dash App:

```
import base64

import datetime

import io

import plotly.graph_objs as go

import dash

from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State

from dash import dcc, html, dash_table

import pandas as pd

import os.path


import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

import plotly.express as px




app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])

 

title = html.H1("Data Visualisation Tool")

foam_title = dbc.Card(

    [

        html.H4(

            "Foam vs Time",className='text-center'

        )

    ]

)

liquid_title = dbc.Card(

    [

        html.H4(

            "Liquid vs Time",className='text-center'

        )

    ]

)

 


#Used to upload Excel files to app
uploader = dcc.Upload(

        id='upload-data',

        children=html.Div([

            'Drag and Drop or ',

            html.A('Select Files')

        ]),

        style={

            'width': '100%',

            'height': '60px',

            'lineHeight': '60px',

            'borderWidth': '1px',

            'borderStyle': 'dashed',

            'borderRadius': '5px',

            'textAlign': 'center',

            'margin': '10px'

        },

        # Allow multiple files to be uploaded

        multiple=True

    )

 




app.layout = dbc.Container(

    [

        dbc.Row(

            [

                dbc.Col([title], width = 6),

                dbc.Col([uploader], width = 6, align = 'end')

            ],

            justify='left',

            id='titlerow,'

        ),

        dbc.Row(

            [

                dbc.Col(

                    [

                        foam_title

                    ],

                    width = 6,

                    id = 'foam_title_col'

                ),

                dbc.Col(

                    [

                        liquid_title

                    ],

                    width = 6,

                    id = 'liquid_title_col'

                )

            ]

        ),


        dbc.Row(

            [

                dbc.Col(

                    [




                    ],

                    width = 12,

                    id = 'graph_row'

                )

            ]

        ),

        dcc.Store(id = 'data_storage'),

        html.Div(id='output-data-upload'),

    ]

,fluid=True

)
#Write function for the bulk of the code here, 
    
def parse_contents(contents, filename, date):


    #df_h = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(decoded), sheet_name = "Height - Raw data")
    basename = []
    for file in filename:
        base = os.path.basename(filename)
        basename.append(filename)
        #print(basename)
    unique_basename = set(basename)
    print(basename)
    df_list = []
    for file in unique_basename:
        content_type, content_string = contents.split(',')
        decoded = base64.b64decode(content_string)
        df_h = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(decoded), sheet_name = "Height - Raw data")
        df_h['filename'] = file
        split = file.split(" Run")
        df_h['sample'] = split[0]
        time_rounded =[]
        for i in df_h["t [s]"]:
            j = round(0.5*round(i/0.5), 2)
            time_rounded.append(j)
        df_h["time_rounded"] = time_rounded
        df_list.append(df_h)
    print(len(df_list))
    big_df = pd.concat(df_list)
    big_df.to_excel("big_df.xlsx")

@app.callback(Output('graph_row', 'children'),

              Input('upload-data', 'contents'),

              State('upload-data', 'filename'),

              State('upload-data', 'last_modified'))

def update_output(list_of_contents, list_of_names, list_of_dates):

    if list_of_contents is not None:

        children = [

            parse_contents(c, n, d) for c, n, d in

            zip(list_of_contents, list_of_names, list_of_dates)]

        return children


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app.run(debug=True)
```

However, when I try to run this code (assuming my input is a file called 'test_Dash.xlsx' I get the following printed out for my basename, which as you recall should just be the filename (one element in the basename list):

```
['test_Dash.xlsx', 'test_Dash.xlsx', 'test_Dash.xlsx', 'test_Dash.xlsx', 'test_Dash.xlsx', 'test_Dash.xlsx', 'test_Dash.xlsx', 'test_Dash.xlsx', 'test_Dash.xlsx', 'test_Dash.xlsx', 'test_Dash.xlsx', 'test_Dash.xlsx', 'test_Dash.xlsx', 'test_Dash.xlsx']
```

Aside from this, the code does seem to work - I generate an excel file called 'big*df'* which contains all of the desired information. However when I try to input multiple files through the app, only the first file gets appended to bigdf. See below where I input two files into the Dash app - test_*Dash and test*Dash2:

```
 * Serving Flask app 'test_15_07_23-reddit-Copy1'
 * Debug mode: on
['test_Dash.xlsx', 'test_Dash.xlsx', 'test_Dash.xlsx', 'test_Dash.xlsx', 'test_Dash.xlsx', 'test_Dash.xlsx', 'test_Dash.xlsx', 'test_Dash.xlsx', 'test_Dash.xlsx', 'test_Dash.xlsx', 'test_Dash.xlsx', 'test_Dash.xlsx', 'test_Dash.xlsx', 'test_Dash.xlsx']
1
['testDash2.xlsx', 'testDash2.xlsx', 'testDash2.xlsx', 'testDash2.xlsx', 'testDash2.xlsx', 'testDash2.xlsx', 'testDash2.xlsx', 'testDash2.xlsx', 'testDash2.xlsx', 'testDash2.xlsx', 'testDash2.xlsx', 'testDash2.xlsx', 'testDash2.xlsx', 'testDash2.xlsx']
1
['test_Dash.xlsx', 'test_Dash.xlsx', 'test_Dash.xlsx', 'test_Dash.xlsx', 'test_Dash.xlsx', 'test_Dash.xlsx', 'test_Dash.xlsx', 'test_Dash.xlsx', 'test_Dash.xlsx', 'test_Dash.xlsx', 'test_Dash.xlsx', 'test_Dash.xlsx', 'test_Dash.xlsx', 'test_Dash.xlsx']
[      t [s]  hfoam [mm]  hliquid [mm]  htotal [mm]  Vfoam [mL]  Vliquid [mL]  Vtotal [mL] FVS [%] FLS [%]  n [rpm] T [°C]        filename          sample  time_rounded
0      0.11        27.5          19.0         46.5        33.3          17.5         50.8      --      --        0     --  test_Dash.xlsx  test_Dash.xlsx           0.0
1      0.31        27.5          19.0         46.5        33.3          17.5         50.8      --      --        0     --  test_Dash.xlsx  test_Dash.xlsx           0.5
2      0.51        27.5          19.0         46.5        33.3          17.5         50.8      --      --        0     --  test_Dash.xlsx  test_Dash.xlsx           0.5
3      0.71        27.5          19.0         46.5        33.3          17.5         50.8      --      --        0     --  test_Dash.xlsx  test_Dash.xlsx           0.5
4      0.91        27.5          19.0         46.5        33.3          17.5         50.8      --      --        0     --  test_Dash.xlsx  test_Dash.xlsx           1.0
..      ...         ...           ...          ...         ...           ...          ...     ...     ...      ...    ...             ...             ...           ...
720  322.91        64.4          27.9         92.3        77.9          28.2        106.1   109.1     161        0     --  test_Dash.xlsx  test_Dash.xlsx         323.0
721  323.41        64.4          27.9         92.3        77.9          28.2        106.1   109.1     161        0     --  test_Dash.xlsx  test_Dash.xlsx         323.5
722  323.91        64.4          27.9         92.3        77.9          28.2        106.1   109.1     161        0     --  test_Dash.xlsx  test_Dash.xlsx         324.0
723  324.41        64.4          27.9         92.3        77.9          28.2        106.1   109.1     161        0     --  test_Dash.xlsx  test_Dash.xlsx         324.5
724  324.91        64.4          27.9         92.3        77.9          28.2        106.1   109.1     161        0     --  test_Dash.xlsx  test_Dash.xlsx         325.0

[725 rows x 14 columns]]
['testDash2.xlsx', 'testDash2.xlsx', 'testDash2.xlsx', 'testDash2.xlsx', 'testDash2.xlsx', 'testDash2.xlsx', 'testDash2.xlsx', 'testDash2.xlsx', 'testDash2.xlsx', 'testDash2.xlsx', 'testDash2.xlsx', 'testDash2.xlsx', 'testDash2.xlsx', 'testDash2.xlsx']
[      t [s]  hfoam [mm]  hliquid [mm]  htotal [mm]  Vfoam [mL]  Vliquid [mL]  Vtotal [mL] FVS [%] FLS [%]  n [rpm] T [°C]        filename          sample  time_rounded
0      0.11        27.5          19.0         46.5        33.3          17.5         50.8      --      --        0     --  testDash2.xlsx  testDash2.xlsx           0.0
1      0.31        27.5          19.0         46.5        33.3          17.5         50.8      --      --        0     --  testDash2.xlsx  testDash2.xlsx           0.5
2      0.51        27.5          19.0         46.5        33.3          17.5         50.8      --      --        0     --  testDash2.xlsx  testDash2.xlsx           0.5
3      0.71        27.5          19.0         46.5        33.3          17.5         50.8      --      --        0     --  testDash2.xlsx  testDash2.xlsx           0.5
4      0.91        27.5          19.0         46.5        33.3          17.5         50.8      --      --        0     --  testDash2.xlsx  testDash2.xlsx           1.0
..      ...         ...           ...          ...         ...           ...          ...     ...     ...      ...    ...             ...             ...           ...
720  322.91        20.3          41.5         61.8        24.5          44.7         69.2    77.9     7.9        0     --  testDash2.xlsx  testDash2.xlsx         323.0
721  323.41        20.3          41.5         61.8        24.5          44.7         69.2    77.9     7.9        0     --  testDash2.xlsx  testDash2.xlsx         323.5
722  323.91        20.3          41.5         61.8        24.5          44.7         69.2    77.9     7.9        0     --  testDash2.xlsx  testDash2.xlsx         324.0
723  324.41        20.3          41.5         61.8        24.5          44.7         69.2    77.9     7.9        0     --  testDash2.xlsx  testDash2.xlsx         324.5
724  324.91        20.3          41.5         61.8        24.5          44.7         69.2    77.9     7.9        0     --  testDash2.xlsx  testDash2.xlsx         325.0

[725 rows x 14 columns]]
```

Annoyingly, only testDash2 is appended to the bigdf excel sheet.

I have tried to get only the unique filename from the basename list by using the`set()`method, this fixes the issue of replicates of each filename being printed out, but it doesn't fix the issue of only one file being appended to the bigdf dataframe. I think the issue may come from the `updateouput` function at the end of the programme, where several of the `parsecontents` arguments are zipped together. The documentation (linked) doesn't give a good description of the update_output function actually does.

Any help or advice would be much appreciated and apologies in advance for such a long post.